Am I Doing Things Right? / negative binomial test
I have a dataset consisting of social media comments about a particular context from 1999 to 2024.The topic titles of the comments were annotated into two categorial variables = 0 and 1.
I am aiming to better understand which topic category tends to receive more comments in different time intervals: within one hour since the initial comment, within a week, a year etc... and within the full timeframe also.
Since each of the data groups do not follow a normal or poisson distribution, and since I am working on count data, I thought negative binomial test would be an adequate approach, rather than poisson or mann-whitney u test.
Here are some results of the test:

Based on the Exp(B), what kind of an interpretation can I make? Can I say, for example, in the one hour interval, the type 0 topics have 34% more chance to receive plus one comment (or comments?) than type 1 topics? Would that be correct to say that?
Thank you for your help!

Given that you have two groups and no other variable, I don't see why you can't use a Mann Whitney U test. Not that NB is wrong but U is much simpler to interpret. And, to estimate differences between groups, you don't even need U, you can just look. (U will give you p values and CIs and so on).

Thanks Peter. But as far as I learned, U is not very suitable for count data. Maybe I am wrong. Also, since there are so many topic titles (around 1000 in total), I thought assessing the statistical significance would be more robust.

I would really appreciate if there are any other helpful comments
